# Javascript loop to return string x times

Tags: javascript

I'm doing Udacity javascript studies now and there is one quiz that bothers me. I know how to do it easily in ruby, but this one is killing me.

I need to call function and return "ha" num times and add "!" at the end with the loop.

I tried this but it didn't help. Should be very simple.

```
function laugh(num) {
  for (var x = 0; num; x ++) {
      return 'ha';
  }
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

Comment: A function returns once.

Comment: i doubt the question is worded like that, you probably dont want to return ha 3 times, you probably want to return a string that has 3 ha's in it. like "ha ha ha!".  there should be one return.

Comment: `return` returns immediately. IOW, the first pass through the loop returns, and the next passes never happen. Clearly that isn't what you intend.

Comment: Var str =""; str+="ha"; return str + "!";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you don't even need the loop.

```js
const laugh = num => 'ha'.repeat(num) + '!';

console.log(laugh(3));
console.log(laugh(5));
```

Comment: Yeah I did it now with .repeat(num) without a loop, but Udacity gives you a tip to use loop.

Comment: @ОлегЯкунин It's just a tip, not a required condition.

Answer (score 2):

Returning in a loop will return the whole function. To make this work you could concatenate the string in the loop and then return the concatenated output. You also formatted your loop incorrectly, you need to tell the loop to stop when x is less than num. Try:

```js
function laugh(num) {
  var laughString = '';
  for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    laughString += 'ha';
  }
  return laughString + '!';
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only `return` once from a function. Try building up the string you need in the loop, then return the value after the loop is done.

(Note: You can have multiple `return` statements in a function, but as soon as you hit one of them the function completes its execution.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function laugh(num) {
  var outString = '';
  for (var x = 0; x<num; x ++) {
    outString += ' ha';
  }
  return outString.substring(1) + '!';
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function laugh(input) {
  var answer = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    answer += 'ha';
  }
  return (answer + '!');
}
```

First, set a variable to an empty string, (it will be your answer)
Then, write a for loop that loops according to the input (you did that)
then inside the for loop you add 'ha' to your answer string
finally outside the for loop (after it has ran all the loops)
return the answer string plus !