# Concatenate Output - Beginner Functions

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, concatenation

This is a very basic function, since I just started to program in JavaScript.

```
function laugh(num) {
    for(var i = 1; i < num ; i += 1) {
        var message = "ha";
        console.log(message);
}
        return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

The output I am getting is:

```
ha
ha
ha!
```

But I need it to be

```
hahaha!
```

I have tried many different strings like trying to use and empty string. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Instead of logging, concatenate. Then log in the very end.

Comment: @Li357 Yes this is the first problem, the second is the `message`  variable declaration which should be before the loop.

Comment: @chsdk `var` declarations are function-scoped. Though it is wrong in appearance and practice, it doesn't cause an error.

Comment: @Li357 Actually it's declared inside the loop, so each iteration will have its own `message`, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47253500/3669624).

Comment: @chsdk Not really. Sure, `message` will get reassigned each iteration, but there is only one `message` in function because it's `var` is function-scoped. At this point it's semantics, no need to argue about that.

Comment: @Li357 Really?!, you can check it and run the code.

Comment: @chsdk I'm not disagreeing that for concatenation you'll need a variable in a higher scope, it's the fact that in the OP's original code, every iteration doesn't "have its own `message`". It's just semantics.

Comment: Yes, I meant that each iteration will override `message` variable ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript loop to return string x times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149893/javascript-loop-to-return-string-x-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message string must be defined before the loop, otherwise you don't concatenate strings, but you just override them:

```
function laugh(num)
{
    var message = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < num ; i += 1)
        message += "ha";

    return message + "!";
}
```

Debugging with `console.log()` has the drawback to append a line break, as other users pointed out, but the problem was not caused by this.

I also modified the loop, because declaring `i` as `1` and `message` as `''` in the beginning would have produced one laugh less than expected! So either you go for:

```
var message = 'ha';
for (var i = 1; i < num ; i += 1)
```

Or you go for:

```
var message = '';
for (var i = 0; i < num ; i += 1)
```

But the first method would produce misleading results if someone applies a common logic to parametrize the function.

Answer (score 1):

You got this output because every `console.log()` call will be printed in a new line, and you need to declare your `message` variable outside the loop.

And you need to form the whole message before logging it.

```
function laugh(num) {
  var message = 'ha';
  for (var i = 1; i < num; i += 1) {
    message += "ha";
  }
  return message + "!";
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function laugh(num) {
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < num; i += 1) {
    message += "ha";
  }
  return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` appends a new line at the end.
Declare `message` before the `for` and store each part into.
Then after the loop, output it at the end with `console.log()` :

```
function laugh(num) {
    var message = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < num ; i += 1) {
        message += "ha";
    }
    console.log(message);
    return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

move initial message outisde of the loop.

```js
function laugh(num) {
    var message = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < num ; i += 1) {
        message += "ha";
    }
        return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(5));
```

below loop just assigns `num` times 'ha to message variable. at the end of loop it just becomes, "ha"+"!" => "ha!". and the function that wraps this loop does not finalize as you expect. the `console.log`s just fakes you -))

```
for(var i = 1; i < num ; i += 1) {
        var message = "ha";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer `for` loop approach to this task, you should *declare* `message` variable as an *empty string* outside `for` loop and then, with every cycle concatenate `ha` to the `message` variable.

```js
function laugh(num) {
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
    message += "ha";
  }
  return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

However, if you want an easier solution and modern one, you should consider `repeat` function:

```js
const smile = (num) => 'ha'.repeat(num) + '!';

console.log(smile(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function laugh(num){
  var message = '' ; 
  for(var i=0;i<num;i++) {
    message= message + "ha";
  } 
  return message + "!";
}

console.log(laugh(3));
```

You do not need the console.log inside your function if you are going to log it outside of the function. Additionally, set a variable outside your for loop and use it to accumulate the message output.